# To fix permissions for backups in reading

Tags: linux, macos, bash, backup, permissions

I see the following kind of folders in reading my backup disc with OSX, similarly forbidden in reading by Debian Linux 8.1. 
The SSD of my Macbook broke two months ago so I have had recover some folders. 
Some folders have however such a sign, while the other not. 
I do not understand why. 
It may be related to the corruption of the disc which occurred at the end of its lifetime.

[image]

I managed to fix the Dropbox's permission denied problem as described [Why Dropbox causes PostgreSQL permission denied errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31514823/54964).
I thought that a similar solution would work here but not.

Output of `ls -lhd /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/Backups.backupdb/Jaris\ MacBook\ Air/2015-06-24-230830/Macintosh\ HD/Users/masi/*`

```
drwxr-xr-x@  3 501  staff   136B Apr  4 16:57 /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/Backups.backupdb/Jaris MacBook Air/2015-06-24-230830/Macintosh HD/Users/masi/Applications
drwx------+  8 501  staff   1.5K Jun 24 14:01 /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/Backups.backupdb/Jaris MacBook Air/2015-06-24-230830/Macintosh HD/Users/masi/Desktop
drwx------+ 11 501  staff   476B Apr 28 23:58 /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/Backups.backupdb/Jaris MacBook Air/2015-06-24-230830/Macintosh HD/Users/masi/Documents
drwx------+  2 501  staff   7.3K Jun 24 12:06 /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/Backups.backupdb/Jaris MacBook Air/2015-06-24-230830/Macintosh HD/Users/masi/Downloads
drwx------+ 68 501  staff   3.0K Jun 23 19:08 /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/Backups.backupdb/Jaris MacBook Air/2015-06-24-230830/Macintosh HD/Users/masi/Dropbox
drwx------+ 65 501  staff   2.2K Jun 24 09:51 /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/Backups.backupdb/Jaris MacBook Air/2015-06-24-230830/Macintosh HD/Users/masi/Library
drwx------+  3 501  staff   170B Sep 13  2013 /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/Backups.backupdb/Jaris MacBook Air/2015-06-24-230830/Macintosh HD/Users/masi/Movies
drwx------+  5 501  staff   204B Sep 19  2013 /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/Backups.backupdb/Jaris MacBook Air/2015-06-24-230830/Macintosh HD/Users/masi/Music
drwx------+  5 501  staff   476B Jun 17 17:11 /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/Backups.backupdb/Jaris MacBook Air/2015-06-24-230830/Macintosh HD/Users/masi/Pictures
drwxr-xr-x@  3 501  staff   136B Aug 20  2013 /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/Backups.backupdb/Jaris MacBook Air/2015-06-24-230830/Macintosh HD/Users/masi/Public
drwxr-xr-x@  2 501  staff    68B Feb 10  2015 /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/Backups.backupdb/Jaris MacBook Air/2015-06-24-230830/Macintosh HD/Users/masi/default
-rw-r--r--@  2 501  staff     0B Feb 21  2015 /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/Backups.backupdb/Jaris MacBook Air/2015-06-24-230830/Macintosh HD/Users/masi/gnuplotrc
-rw-------+  2 501  staff   2.4K Jan 24  2015 /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/Backups.backupdb/Jaris MacBook Air/2015-06-24-230830/Macintosh HD/Users/masi/mbox
-rw-r--r--@  1 501  staff   105K Oct 17  2014 /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/Backups.backupdb/Jaris MacBook Air/2015-06-24-230830/Macintosh HD/Users/masi/test2.tex
-rw-r--r--@  1 501  staff   295B Feb  2  2015 /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/Backups.backupdb/Jaris MacBook Air/2015-06-24-230830/Macintosh HD/Users/masi/texput.log
```

Output of Marius's answer

```
sudo chown masi /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/Backups.backupdb/Jaris\ MacBook\ Air/2015-06-24-230830/Macintosh\ HD/Users/masi/*
chown: /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/Backups.backupdb/Jaris MacBook Air/2015-06-24-230830/Macintosh HD/Users/masi/Applications: Operation not permitted
chown: /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/Backups.backupdb/Jaris MacBook Air/2015-06-24-230830/Macintosh HD/Users/masi/Desktop: Operation not permitted
...
```

About mounting, I run `sudo mount -u -w /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/` but get

```
mount: unknown special file or file system /Volumes/HD-PNFU3/.
```

How can you read your backup files of forbidden folders?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42952/how-should-i-correct-the-owners-and-permissions-in-an-os-x-user-folder does this helps?

Comment: Could you please post the output of  ls -lhd * from the directory in which you see Documents, Downloads, Dropbox and so on

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I added the output of your command.

Comment: If you mount it as an external disk on Mac, you should be able to Get Info on the volume & check 'ignore ownership'

Answer (score 1):

From the output of `ls -lhd *` it looks like you are not the owner of the directories in question, and you do not have access permissions to them. You can fix them simply by running the following command:

```
  sudo chown YourName *
```

in the directory which contains the unaccessible files. If the same problem occurs for directories inside the directories above, use instead, always from the same directory:

```
  sudo chown -R YourName *
```

If this does not work, then it is because of how you mounted the disk, but we'll cross that bridge when we get there.

EDIT:

Time to cross that bridge. You will have to mount the disk with read **and write** permissions. This is done so, in Unix (in Linux it is slightly different):

```
   sudo mount -u -w /Volumes/YourDriveName
```

Now the `chown` command should work.

Comment: I added the output of your commands in the body of the question, getting *operation not permitted* notices.

Comment: @Masi Please read my Edit.

Comment: I added the second edit to your answer in the body of my question. I tried unsuccessfully mounting the whole disc. I did the command in OSX. I have here Debian Linux too so if necessary. What is your distro?

Comment: @Masi I use Debian, Arch Linux, OpenBSD. But the answer you receive indicates a corrupt disk!

Comment: The disc is an external Buffalo (2 TB) which is 2 months old. However, those files were backups of the system which had a corrupted disc. I think it may be the reason for this like you point out.